# Jfreechart: how to make a histogram that has Strings in the x axis and Integers in the y axis?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a Hashmap

the values are just strings and the Integers a number that represents the amount of times the String appears in a text

I would like to use this hashmap in order to create a histogram or a graph in general that would have in the x axis, the Strings from the hashmap

and in the y axis the Integers associated with them

Is this possible? How would I approach this problem?

Most of the examples I've seen are just on ints and doubles

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hashmap<String, Integer>` sounds like a job for `CategoryDataset` and a bar chart; the [`BarChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html) [source](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html#line.65) is included in the distribution.